# Duplicate Values Occur When trying to fetch last transaction of a product

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

how to avoid Duplicate Values Occur When trying to fetch last transaction of a product from a table.  my query as follows my image is like [image]

```
SELECT
  a.branchid,
  a.TellerID,
  a.ProductID,
  a.TransactDateTime,
  a.ProductStock,
  a.ProductStockInLocalCrrncy
FROM ALX_SubInventoryCashTransfers a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        branchid,
        TellerID,
        ProductID,
        MAX(TransactDateTime) datetime
    FROM ALX_SubInventoryCashTransfers
    GROUP BY branchid,
            TellerID,
            ProductID,
            TransactDateTime
) tm
  ON a.BranchID = tm.BranchID
  AND a.branchid = tm.BranchID
  AND a.TellerID = tm.TellerID
  AND a.ProductID = tm.ProductID
  AND a.TransactDateTime = tm.datetime
```

Comment: Can you show us the real output containing the duplicates?  The screen capture you included shows multiple `datetime` values, which isn't possible from your query since you limit to records having the max from a certain table.

Comment: Try by removing TransactDateTime field from group by clause.

Comment: @ tim, it is the duplicate. i need only one date one product value. you can see in the pic product ID 2 repeats twice in the same say , i need it only once in a day

Comment: @vicky , ya i had done that also then also same i fetch only date and shown same thing occur

Comment: @vicky i need date to display for each product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove TransactDateTime from group by

```
from ALX_SubInventoryCashTransfers  group by
branchid,TellerID,ProductID,**TransactDateTime**) tm
```

You can try this query

```
SELECT
  a.branchid,
  a.TellerID,
  a.ProductID,
  a.TransactDateTime,
  a.ProductStock,
  a.ProductStockInLocalCrrncy
FROM ALX_SubInventoryCashTransfers a
INNER JOIN (SELECT
  branchid,
  TellerID,
  ProductID,
  MAX(TransactDateTime) as MaxDate
FROM ALX_SubInventoryCashTransfers
GROUP BY branchid,
         TellerID,
         ProductID) tm
  ON a.BranchID = tm.BranchID
  AND a.branchid = tm.BranchID
  AND a.TellerID = tm.TellerID
  AND a.ProductID = tm.ProductID
  AND a.TransactDateTime = tm.MaxDate
```

Comment: i need date accoding to the date i need to display( each product last value should be display in each day)

Comment: I am saying to remove only from group by.. You can use the maxdate from subquery

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
with cte as (
    select
        rn = row_number() over ( partition by a.ProductID order by a.TransactDateTime desc),
        a.branchid, a.TellerID, a.ProductID, a.TransactDateTime, a.ProductStock, a.ProductStockInLocalCrrncy 
    from
        ALX_SubInventoryCashTransfers a
)
select
    a.branchid, a.TellerID, a.ProductID, a.TransactDateTime, a.ProductStock, a.ProductStockInLocalCrrncy 
from
    cte a
where
    ( a.rn = 1 )
```

Comment: it is not showing correct with cte it will be like page wise show

Answer (score 1):

If I got your issue correctly, you want max of datetime for each date. Try the below query:

```
SELECT
  a.branchid,
  a.TellerID,
  a.ProductID,
  a.TransactDateTime,
  a.ProductStock,
  a.ProductStockInLocalCrrncy
FROM ALX_SubInventoryCashTransfers a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        branchid,
        TellerID,
        ProductID,
        MAX(TransactDateTime) datetime
    FROM ALX_SubInventoryCashTransfers
    GROUP BY branchid,
            TellerID,
            ProductID,
            CAST(TransactDateTime AS DATE)
) tm
  ON a.BranchID = tm.BranchID
  AND a.branchid = tm.BranchID
  AND a.TellerID = tm.TellerID
  AND a.ProductID = tm.ProductID
  AND a.TransactDateTime = tm.datetime
```